# Контейнер для файлов

Tags: c++, контейнеры

Какой использовать контейнер для файлов `std::ifstream`, если надо поддерживать добавление в конец/удаление произвольного/проход по всем файлам? Можно даже не поддерживать добавление в конец, а чтобы можно было добавить 1 раз при создании контейнера.

`std::vector` работает, но медленно удаляет.

`std::set` не работает -- нужен оператор <.

`std::unordered_set` не работает -- нужен хеш.

Не понимаю, как можно сравнивать/хешировать такие объекты.

Comment: ну еще std::list есть

Comment: @user7860670 точно, `std::forward_list` как раз подходит, спасибо

Comment: std::vector работает медленно? сколько же элементов в нем?

Comment: @KoVadim ну удаление линейное

Comment: то есть, из за того, что Вы считаете, что удаление линейное, это сразу автоматом медленнее? Профилировали? Но если у Вас будет много-много удалений-добавлений элементов в список, то очень скоро Вы узнаете, что вектор он очень быстрый

Comment: @KoVadim линейное медленнее константного

Comment: смелое утверждение. Добавление-удаление в список не есть константным в общем случае. Но если нужно, удаление произвольного элемента с вектора можно сделать почти константным.

Comment: @KoVadim в документации написано, что удаление константное у списка. Как сделать удаление у вектора почти константным?

Comment: математически да. Но по факту нет. Я не даром написал о "частом добавлении-удалении элементов". В этом случае вступает в игру менеджер памяти. А ему бывает нужно побежать по своей внутренней структуре и найти подходящий блок. А если очень часто добавлять удалять, то может быть дефрагментация памяти. И может очень больно ударить.   По моему опыту, у меня был сервис, который держал вектор небольших структур, размером 1000-1500, который постоянно обновлялся. И замена на std::list дала сильную просадку (было замечено по общему кол-ву пользователей сервиса). Но на бумаге все выглядело красиво.

Comment: @KoVadim ок, попробую вектор замерять тоже, у меня не очень частые удаления на самом деле

Comment: только бенчмарк покажет, нужно ли заменять или нет. Если порядок элементов в векторе не очень важен (а раз Вы смотрели на set, то это так), то для удаления элемента с середины просто заменяйте его элементом с конца (ну и размер потом уменьшить аккуратно).

Comment: @KoVadim действительно, порядок не важен и можно так сделать, спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Раз Вам порядок не важен (Вы же смотрели на std::set), вместо обычного удаления элемента, просто заменяйте его последним элементом. А последний элемент просто выбрасывайте. Правда, если конструкторы и деструкторы немного не тривиальны, возможно нужно будет "доработать напильником. Скорость удаления будет константной (ну или очень близкой к ней).

Использование std::list хоть и выглядит хорошо, но по факту дает ощутимый результат только в очень редких случаях. std::list хранит каждый свой элемент в отдельном куске памяти, а значит данные могут лежать разбросанными по памяти (привет кешам и просадке скорости прохода по элементам в несколько раз, а то и десяток раз). Также список очень не дружелюбен к менеджерам памяти. Поэтому, в высоконагруженных приложениях его применяют только после профилирования или обкладывания своим аллокатором.

Вот одно с интересных сравнений https://baptiste-wicht.com/posts/2012/11/cpp-benchmark-vector-vs-list.html